# Phase of synced oscillators in analog synthesizers

Tags: synthesizer, electronics, synthesis

Most explanations of oscillator (hard) sync in synthesizers focus on the theoretical idea of retriggering the oscillator (using simple diagrams), or on the frequency spectrum of the resulting waveform. What I'm looking for is the practical result of how this was implemented in classic analog synths such as a Prophet or Jupiter, and more specifically:

1. At which point in the waveform of the master oscillator does the retriggering occur?
2. At which point in its waveform does the synced oscillator start?

and this for the standard waveforms: sawtooth, square, pulse, triangle, sine.

*MASTER OSCILLATOR*

*Square/Pulse*: does the retriggering happen when the waveform starts to rise from its minimum value, when is passes zero, or when it reaches the maximum?

*Sawtooth*: does the retriggering happen when the waveform starts to rise from its minimum value, when is passes zero, or when it reaches the maximum? Or maybe when it passes zero in the ramp phase instead of the jump phase?

*Triangle/Sine*: does the retriggering happen when the waveform is at its minimum value, when it passes zero, or when it's at its maximum value?

*SYNCED OSCILLATOR*

*Square/Pulse*: does the waveform start at its minimum value and then rise immediately, or does is start from zero, or does it start from its maximum value?

*Sawtooth*: does the waveform start at its minimum value and then rise immediately, or does is start from zero and rise immediately, or does it start from its maximum value? Or does it start from zero in the ramp phase instead of the jump phase?

*Triangle/sine*: does the waveform start at its minimum value, at zero, or at its maximum value?

I'm looking for descriptions or oscilloscope images or diagrams about actual analog synthesizers, not for theoretical diagrams that explain the concept but may not reflect actual implementations.

Comment: Hi, your question is certainly interesting but I suspect this is unfortunately not a good fit for this site, firstly because it is so broad, and secondly because you have not told us anything about an actual problem you need to solve. Per the [site guidance](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face", and "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question" [which I can here!], "you’re asking too much."

Comment: @RegEdit The problem I'm trying to solve is how to authentically recreate oscillator sync in software. The scope is limited to the six cases that I listed. The answer could be as straightforward as "retriggering happens when the master oscillator goes through zero in the jump phase and the synced oscillator always starts at maximum value."

Comment: As @RegEdit says, this is probably off-topic here. A good place to start is the [schematics for a Prophet 5](https://medias.audiofanzine.com/files/sequentialcircuitsprophet-5servicemanual-text-470674.pdf), with the circuit in question on p. 50.  You'll of course also need the [datasheet for the CEM3340](http://www.bustedgear.com/images/datasheets/CEM3340-3345.pdf) voltage-controlled oscillator.  (You might also try your question on electronics.stackexchange.com where I might contribute an answer.)

Comment: @Theodore Thanks. The last few pages of the CEM3340 datasheet contain some useful info and a diagram. Apparently its hard sync is implemented as a reversing sync for the triangle, a mirror sync for the square wave, and a combination of the two for the sawtooth.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**:

We've both been kind of fooled by the way the documents are worded on oscillator sync. This is because no one wants to explain exactly how analog synth VCOs are designed in the user manual for a synth. Quoting from [an electronic music wiki](https://electronicmusic.fandom.com/wiki/VCO_core) (emphasis mine):

> The two parts of a basic VCO core are a circuit that charges a capacitor at a rate determined by the input control voltage, and **a timing mechanism that "resets" the waveform back to its starting point** by discharging the capacitor.

It's not that the final output waveform of the master oscillator is somehow analyzed and used to reset the synced oscillator. It's much simpler than that. The reset timer from the master oscillator core is connected to the reset mechanism for the synced oscillator core. It's that simple.

---

Every design I’ve read the specs for says the synced oscillator is reset when the voltage of the master oscillator reaches zero, or when the master oscillator is reset itself. Note that oscillators are not necessarily symmetrical around zero, so the synced oscillator usually resets only once per cycle of the master oscillator.

The question about what counts as the start of the cycle for the synced oscillator doesn’t matter, because whether the initial value for the oscillator is low or high is an inaudible difference. The square wave is a perfect example of this. It’s the exact same shape no matter whether it starts low or high. Hard sync on a square wave is essentially the same as pulse width modulation, and pulse waves are also the same whether they start low or high. Another way to think about it is that a 25% duty cycle is just an inverted 75% duty cycle, and inverting a waveform does not really change anything about it except the convention by which it’s displayed (as long as you’re not recombining that wave with a non-inverted copy).

You can find specific explanations of analog hard sync in manuals. I would check the Sequential web site and the Moog web site.

As commenters have noted, there are potentially as many different answers to your questions as there are designs for hard sync circuits. In practice, however, there are a small number of very popular implementations, on which I have based the answer.

Comment: Would that pass-through-zero be in the jump phase or the ramp phase of a sawtooth wave? I.e. passing from - to + in a rising or falling sawtooth. That would make a significant difference.

Comment: @user85294 In the Moog voyager manual, it shows that the voyager sawtooth has a zero value at either the bottom or top of the sawtooth. Since they both happen at almost exactly the same time (on the timescale of a single cycle) it doesn’t matter whether zero is at the bottom or the top. Note that the voyager sawtooth never passes from - to +. It is not symmetrical around zero. It is either all positive or all negative and only hits zero once per cycle.

Comment: I see. The CEM3340 datasheet also shows the oscillators outputting only positive voltages. That mostly settles my questions about the sawtooth and square/pulse waves. Now I have to find the phase relation between the triangle and sawtooth wave (it seems the one is usually converted from the other).

Comment: @user85294 I'm going to make an edit that you should check out.

Comment: When talking about "positive only" voltages, don't forget that somewhere near the outputs of the synthesizer (or at least at the input of the amplifier or recording equipment) is a DC blocking capacitor that will have the effect of centering the waveform around zero.